# ubuntu didn`t got to desktop when restarted?

Tags: desktop-environments

I just put the java path manually in ubuntu OS and saved. Then we restarted the system. after that,it didnt go to desktop, browser etc and even the settings of ubuntu. I put the correct password but dont move forward.please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't know what release of Ubuntu you are using (you didn't say), nor what desktop environment you are talking about (GNOME is default desktop for some releases, Unity is default for another).  You also weren't specific on where you added the *java path* thus it may have been a temporary location (lost on reboot), or catastrophic on next reboot.  Also when entering the correct password? (GUI or TUI?) do you return to the greeter as if nothing was done (which can occur with lack of disk space in your user directory; GUI login can't proceed & aborts). Have you logged in via text terminal?

Comment: i used ubuntu 19.10 version, desktop GNOME. I added the path in text editer, opened by command (gedit ~/.pam_environment
) then restart my laptop which can get the password but do not move ahead. thanks